# .pylintrc - disable error doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

I get this false-positive warning when i run `pylint` on my code,

```
E: 56, 7: Instance of 'bool' has no 'status_code' member (but some 
types could not be inferred) (maybe-no-member)
```

From the [pylint-site](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages), i see the code for above error is `E1103`. I added the following code in `.pylintrc` under `MESSAGES CONTROL` section as,

```
disable=E1103, E1101
```

It didn't suppress the warning.

Surprisingly, passing the disable flag explicitly worked,

```
pylint -E --disable=maybe-no-member filename.py
```

How can i make these disable flags part of `.pylintrc`, so that i don't need to pass them everytime?

Comment: Wild guess, have you tried using disable without spaces after commas? I'm not sure this is an issue, but I've never seen spaces after commas in pylint.rc files. Maybe space is the reason `disable` isn't parsed correctly, therefore ignored? I can add a full answer after you'll confirm / disprove.

Comment: removing spaces, doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure your .pylintrc file is used in analysis? Try specifying it explicitly: `pylint [args] --rcfile=path/to/.pylintrc`

Answer (score 1):

There is several things in there...

Firstly, you should stop using old short message identifier (E1103), rather use the new explicit ones (maybe-no-member). You can use both directly, either on the command line or in the configuration file. The long identifier is supplied in the message.

Secondly, there is no problem specifying some part of the configuration into the pylintrc file and to complete it (or even override it) using the command line.

If you can't achieve the same effect using the pylintrc file vs the command line, ensure your pylintrc file is properly loaded (you shouldn't see "No config file found, using default configuration" right after starting pylint). You may as suggested try to use the `--rcfile` option to specify it.

Last but not least, you may want to try the `--help-msg` option to get extra-information about a message (such as description and long/short id).

Answer (score 0):

You should use either the command line options or the configuration file. It will not work if you use both.

So in your case use any of these:

```
pylint -E --disable=E1103 filename.py
```

(or)

Specify the following in the configuration file:
disable=E1103, W, C, F

```
disable=E1103, C, W, F
```

Comment: i stopped passing disable option via cmdline and had set the `disable` codes in .pylintrc. Still, it didn't work.